# mongodb find followed by update semantics

Tags: c++, mongodb, database, nosql

[This page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) shows a update reaching into a previously retrieved (find) document and querying a subelement (array) to update it. I pretty much need to do the exact same thing. Code for the example:

```
> t.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4b97e62bf1d8c7152c9ccb74"), "title" : "ABC",
  "comments" : [ { "by" : "joe", "votes" : 3 }, { "by" : "jane", "votes" : 7 } ] }

> t.update( {'comments.by':'joe'}, {$inc:{'comments.$.votes':1}}, false, true )
```

What are the rules governing find-followed-by-update, I haven't noticed an explanation for this in the documentation. Does the same stuff apply to use of mongodb via drivers ? A link to the relevant semantics would be helpful. I am using the C++ driver.

**edit: self answer**

the 2 commands can be rolled into one (and this is one way of removing the ambiguity this question raises), the query part of an update can refer to a array sub-element, and the `$` symbol will reference to it. I assume you can only reference one sub-element in the query part of an update operation. In my case the update operation looks as follows :

```
db.qrs.update ( { "_id" : ObjectId("4f1fa126adf93ab96cb6e848"), "urls.u_id" : 171 }, { "$inc" :  { "urls.$.CC": 1} })
```

The `_id` correctly "primes" the right unique row, and the second query element `"urls.u_id" : 171` assures that the row in question has the right field. `urls.$.CC` then routes the `$inc` operation to the correct array entry.

**recomendation to any mongodb dev or document writer**

Do not show examples which have potential race conditions in them. Always avoid showing multiple operations that can be done atomically.

Comment: @self answer. You are incorrectly assuming that the example shows a two step operation. It doesn't. The author is simply showing the structure of the documents in the collection to the reader with a find before showing an update example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are relatively straightforward. The results of the update may or may not be available to any subsequent reads depending on a number of things (slaveOk true/false in combination with repsets, update and find using different connections, write safety). You can guarantee it to be available if you do a safe write (w >= 1) and perform the find on the same connection. Most drivers offer functionality for this (typically "requestStart" and "requestDone").

All that said, there's a much better solution available to you for this, namely findAndModify. This operation finds a document, updates it and returns either the old version of the document or the newly updated version. This command is available in the C++ driver. For a reference look here : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command

EDIT : Please note that the "find" in the example is only there to show the reader of the documentation what the structure/schema of the documents inside the collection is to place the subsequent "update" in context. The "update" operation is in no way affected by the "find" before it.

Comment: I meant the rules after the find. `t.update( {'comments.by' : `joe`} ...)` is referencing an object that was uniquely identified in the previous find operation :D. Which sort of says to me "if find has found a previous unique row, make it available to a subsequent update operation. :D

Comment: Hm? No it has nothing to do with eachother. The update operation finds  the document or documents that match it's criteria and updates them. The find is there for illustration only and in no, way shape or form affects the update operation that follows it.

Comment: In that case the query is saying update the vote count of "comments by Joe" in every article ? Is that what the example is trying to illustrate ? The first find would prime the specific article. As an example and a realistic use-case it would only make sense if a comment within a specific article got an upvote.

Comment: Again, there is no priming. There is no relationship between the two commands. If the find wasn't included in the example the update would have the exact same results. Every command in MongoDB stands on it's own.

Comment: Thats the reason for confusion. The commands stand on their own, yet the example used illustrates a non-sense use-case. You upvote comments on specific articles, not a comment made in every article.

Comment: Agreed in this case. The update upvotes all comments by "joe" which is a nonsense use case